Can I perform a clean install of Windows 11, will it automatically fetch the key and activate it like it does for Windows 10?
I have a Lenovo Thinkpad P51. Below are the specs:

Intel i7 7820HQ
16GB RAM
512 GB NVMe SSD
Nvidia Quadro M1200
Intel HD 630

Currently, I'm on Windows 11. I updated through Windows 10 by changing the registry. My laptop has an OEM key which automatically activates Windows 10 and when I update to 11, it keeps it activated even though Windows 11 is not supported on my laptop.
Now my question is if I do a clean install of Windows 11 on my system using a USB, will it automatically fetch the key and activate it like it does for Windows 10? Is there a way to find the key through Command Prompt and use it to activate Windows 11?
Also right now I get regular updates: security and feature. If I do a clean install will I still be getting the updates or not?

could you check 'how' the system's activated? I usually search for system > activation - and include what's in the drop down?

Your system seems modern enough to have the key stored in UEFI/BIOS. Meaning that a clean install will use the same key and activate without problem.

@JourneymanGeek It says Windows is activated with a digital license linked to your Microsoft account. I did link my account much later on my Windows 11. Used to run on domain account.

Then it should be fine, though there's a risk updates will break - not cause of activation, but of the 'hacks' used to bypass the feature checks failing. That said, a 7th gen should be supported, what're you missing, TPM?

@JourneymanGeek The laptop has TPM 2.0 and Secure boot. The generation of the CPU is the only problem.

"even though Windows 11 is not supported on my laptop." You do realize that Microsoft has closed some of the loopholes that allowed non-compliant PC's to run Win11? Updates may fail, or the system may no longer boot after an update: https://www.extremetech.com/computing/326450-microsoft-will-allow-old-systems-to-install-windows-11-just-not-automatically, https://hackaday.com/2024/02/16/the-latest-windows-11-release-might-not-work-on-your-oldest-machines/ . Consider buying another PC to run Win 11, or trying another OS (e.g., Linux) on the existing Lenovo.

My issue is that I use a lot of softwares that are not supported on Linux and I cant use the alternatives because clients demand certain softwares like Premiere. Can I have a Linux based system and use some Windows-specific software through Wine or some VM option. I doubt it would run great because of the limited resources in my laptop.

The command to retrieve your Windows Product Key is:
wmic path softwarelicensingservice get OA3xOriginalProductKey

When doing a clean install, it's always a good idea to run this command first and storing your key somewhere safe so you can re-apply it if necessary.

Glad the answer was what you were looking for. Please do take heed of what JourneymanGeek is saying though. Once you're happy with your Win11 build, use clonezilla to clone your functional Win11 system disk as a backup so you can restore back to your build at any time. Make sure all your important data is on an external HDD so it's safe. Win11 could stop functioning at any point via windows updates if any sort of bypass has been used to install it or continue using it. Good Luck!

I'm fairly certain it'll work out of the box, so I'm confused why OP has hacks to get their system to work. But yeah, backing up a known good install feels like a good idea :D
